# Choose custom iOS compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an app that recently got rejected because it doesn't work well on iPhone 4/4s or iPad. Is there a way in Xcode to say that it's only for certain models?

Comment: You can set minimal os to iOS8 it will remove iPhone4 , but this is not applies for iPhone4s , still 4s is faster and you can to optimize your app for this

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, try to optimize your application for those devices

Comment: This should be comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define models as such; you define capabilities. You can sometimes use these to cull models as well, but only if your app legitimately uses whatever it is you're testing for.

An example: Bluetooth LE is only available 4s+. You can set your app to require this (or other certain hardware options) via plist keys (UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities  - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) but only if your app actually uses BTLE. You will very likely get rejected if you "require" something you're not using.

Between iPad and non-iPad devices, you control that directly by what you select in the Deployment Info:Devices section of your project.

Answer (score 0):

As annoying as it may be, you should totally modify your UI to be compatible, at least, with all iPhone models.

I assume you've built a layout that is made to fit exactly to the 4" screen. An easy solution would be to put your views into a scrollView instead of just on your view controller's view directly. Then you can at least scroll the UI to see it more easily on the iPhone 4.

But really, your solution should be to adopt auto layout and size classes, and make your UI completely compatible with all iOS devices. It's well worth the effort because it opens your audience to more users, and reduces the risk of poor ratings like "looks bad on iPad even though its not made for iPad. One Star."